# Laravel Query Builder if else OR case to sum

Tags: sql, laravel

I have kind of data

```
order:
id      name         date       payment
----------------------------------------
1       Amy's      2019-1-15      Cash                
2       Hotel1's   2019-1-18      Visa                       

orderdetail:
id       orderid    food      number                            
----------------------------------------------
1           1         1          3            
2           1         2          1            
3           1         3          3            
4           1         4          2            
5           2         1          1            
6           2         3          1            

food:
food     name         type     fee            
-------------------------------------------
1        Apple          1       4                         
2        Beef           2      15                   
3        Orange         1       3                 
4        Apple pie      1       7
```

I obtained this data using this sql query(but not fulfill my result, missing subcost of type1)

```
Order::query()
->select('order.name', 'order.date', DB::raw('(CASE WHEN food.type = 1 THEN SUM(orderdetail.number*food.fee) END) AS type1subcost'),'orderdetail.number*food.fee as totalcost', 'order.payment')
->leftJoin('orderdetail', 'Order.id', '=', 'orderdetail.orderid')
->leftJoin('food', 'order.food', '=', 'food.id')
->get();
```

What i got:

```
    order name/food name       date       type1subcost   totalcost   payment
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
order1-->  Amy's             2019-1-15        35            50         Cash
           Amy's             2019-1-15                      50         Cash
order2-->  Hotel1's          2019-1-18         7             7         Visa
```

I want to get the result like:

```
    order name/food name       date       type1subcost   totalcost   payment
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
order1-->  Amy's             2019-1-15        35            50         Cash
order2-->  Hotel1's          2019-1-18         7             7         Visa
```

and i only want this result from one sql. It's a better way to get my result?

Comment: Why 35 and 50 for `type1subcost` and `totalcost` in your expected result? What would be there if the 2nd result was 10 for `type1subcost` and 30 for `totalcost` instead?

Comment: Just add a groupBy('name'); will do ?

Comment: `'order.food'`? `order` doesn't have any `food` column.